# IF Statement using getElementsByTagName() value on XML DOM using Java

Tags: java, xml, parsing, dom, screen-scraping

I have a XML file called **feed.xml** and I'm using DOM package on JAVA to scrap data.

I was able to scrap data successfully, and now I need to be able to create IF Statements depending on the data I get from the XML.

My problem is that even tough I assign the attribute data in a String variable, when I compare using IF, the condition returns FALSE, when it should be actually right.

This is some of my XML

```
<inventory>
    <item UnitID="1234" Record="0">
        <id>1234</id>
        <dealerid>455</dealerid>
        <stock_number>1600Xtreme</stock_number>
        <make>Nvidia</make>                       
    </item>
    <item UnitID="7854" Record="1">
        <id>7854</id>
        <dealerid>587</dealerid>
        <stock_number>12TMAX5500</stock_number>
        <make>Realtek</make> 
    </item>
</inventory>
```

This is some of my JAVA code for scraping data, and also the IF statement I pretend to use:

```
File fXmlFile=new File("feed.xml");
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory=DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder=dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc=dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
NodeList nList=doc.getElementsByTagName("item");
for (int temp=0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++)
{
    Node nNode=nList.item(temp);
    Element eElement2=(Element)nNode;
    String search="Nvidia";
    System.out.println("This is the value to search from my variable: " + 
    search); //This prints Nvidia
    String toTest=(eElement2.getAttribute("make"));
    System.out.println("toTest is equal to: " + toTest); //This prints 
    Nvidia
    if (toTest == search)
    {
        System.out.println("The condition on the IF is True");
    }
}
```

I should get as output:
"The condition on the IF is True"

However I get nothing since according to JAVA is not TRUE.

I have researched and tried many different ways to make the comparisons but nothing seems to work. (It worked for me if I compare Integers, but in this case is a String) I appreciate your answers.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `.equals` when comparing objects. `==` will not return true for `String`s, even if they contain the same information, as `==` compares by reference, while `.equals` compares by value.

So change it to `if (toTest.equals(search))`.

Answer (score 0):

`UnitID` and `Record` are the attributes of `item` node. `make` is a child node to `item` node. So, you will need to get the text content on the "make" node in order to retrieve its value. Try the below code:

```
File fXmlFile=new File("feed.xml");
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory=DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder=dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc=dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
NodeList nList=doc.getElementsByTagName("item");

for (int temp=0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++)
    {
        Node nNode=nList.item(temp);
        if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            NodeList children = nNode.getChildNodes();
            for(int i = 0; i < children.getLength(); i++) {
                Node childNode = children.item(i);
                if (childNode.getNodeName() == "make"){
                    String make = childNode.getTextContent();
                    if ("Nvidia".equals(make)) {
                        System.out.print(childNode.getTextContent()); // This will print Nvidia
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```